# Nodejs Model Does Not Take Type of Image?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a nodejs project and have created a form that takes in an image file. However, for the model I created, when I try to add the option of an image, I get an error saying Image is not defined. Any suggestions?

```
// Modules required to run the application
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const RecipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    recipeName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    recipeImage: {
        type: Image,
        required: true
    },
    directions: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
});

const Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe', RecipeSchema);

module.exports  = Recipe;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the code that you execute in Node, while JavaScript is not run in the context of a browser. Specifically, the Node process does not have an `Image` object that exists on the global.

You'll need to define your schema to store either the raw binary data or upload the image to a media server and store the URL in your database

Comment: exactly this ^^^^  passing your upload through the multer npm module makes this very easy and allows you to limit the size of the file uploaded to lighten the load on your db.

Comment: This information seems very promising, I'll look into this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can store them as binary data type, please refer to [GridFs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)  for the details.

Alternatively, you can encode them into base64, if those images are relatively small. Another option is to simply store the URL of the image, that would make your DB lighter.